# WPF Grid Mouse Events

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouseevent, wpf-grid

I was wondering, what is the best way to capture a mouse Event inside of a wpf `Grid`?

I wanted to Capture an event when the mouse wheel is either scrolled up or down in the `Grid`.

I tried to create a custom grid, but that kind of didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can hook [the MouseWheel event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousewheel.aspx) or, if you're inheriting, you can override [the OnMouseWheel method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onmousewheel.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I handled mouse event inside a grid by placing a blank Label inside so that it will expand through the Grid and then providing a handler to that.